# How to get the latest activity of a Github Repository in Python?

Tags: python, github, github-api

I want to get all the latest changes possible like commits, pull requests, issues, their comments, discussions, etc of a Github repository.

For that, I want to create some decorators such as `@repo.on_new_commit()` or `@repo.on_new_issue_comment()`, where `repo` is a Github `Repo` object with at least the repository name. The code will always be running and I want `@repo.on_new_commit()` to return the new `commit` immediately when the commit occurs. Or a single decorator `@repo.on_update()` which returns all new changes.

How can I do that? Any suggestion is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the exact answer. This can only be done through [GitHub Webhooks](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events) and a server like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) (for Python)

Everytime a new event happens, github sends a `POST request` to the `payload url` defined by the user in the `webhooks`. Through that, you can easily extract the `json data` from the body along with the `github event` from the request headers and do any external work you want!

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

GIT! and the OS module
like

```
import os
#get activy
activity=os.system('git log github.com/githubuser/repo')
```

so our 'activity' variable is our
activity and the one on top is the latest!

Comment: That's not what I want. You are talking about tracking git changes and not Github.

Comment: git track github?

Comment: If I track using this, firstly `git commit` on local directory doesn't mean they have been pushed to github too afaik. Secondly, this would only tell the commit changes and not anything else.